# Use the Binomial Theorem to show that $0 = \sum_{k=0}^ n (-1)^{k} {n \choose k }$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Use the Binomial Theorem to show that "$$0 = \sum_{k=0}^ n (-1)^{k}  { n \choose k}$$".

Comment: Use $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^n$ and then substitute $x=-1$.

Comment: Don't use \$\$ in titles.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-1)^n=\sum_{x=0}^n {n\choose x}(-1)^x=0$$

Conisder the following expansion $$(x-a)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}x^{n-i}(-a)^i$$. . In your question $x =1$ and $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try expanding $(1-1)^n$, using the binomial theorem.

Comment: (When $n>0$)${}{}{}$

Comment: Verily, the need for that condition is clear.